# Jmeter Jgit JSR223Sampler javax.script.ScriptException error

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jgit

I am using Jgit with Jmeter to clone multiple git repositories. I am cloning 10 different repositories through 10 thread users.

Below is the code which I am using.

```
  import org.eclipse.jgit.api.Git;
  import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
  import org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.RevCommit;
  import org.eclipse.jgit.transport.UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider;
  import org.eclipse.jgit.transport.CredentialsProvider;
  def url_var = vars.get("repo_url");
  log.info("This is the URL " + url_var)
  Git git = Git.cloneRepository().setURI( url_var ).call();
```

I am getting below error while running test.

`o.a.j.p.j.s.JSR223Sampler: Problem in JSR223 script JSR223 Sampler, message: javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.JGitInternalException: Destination path ".git" already exists and is not an empty directory
javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.JGitInternalException: Destination path ".git" already exists and is not an empty directory
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:158) ~[groovy-all-2.4.10.jar:2.4.10]
    at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_73]
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.processFileOrScript(JSR223TestElement.java:222) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JSR223Sampler.sample(JSR223Sampler.java:69) [ApacheJMeter_java.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:491) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:425) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:254) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_73]`

Out of 10 threads, 8 would succeed with clone operation and 2 fails with above error. I am not specifying any destination, hence repo directories are created at default jmeter bin directory. I tried specifying repo dir but it would still fail with **already exists and is not an empty directory** error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a different folder per repository, clean it before running the command and run the clone part.